# Folder being used for another process on batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a issue with a backup script I wrote. The backup is pretty simple. It will copy a directory to a destination path, and then zip it. I have a few `If` clauses to, example, delete the oldest backup if there are 5 or more .zip from previous backups.

The problem I'm facing is: after the `XCOPY` command has finished running I then run a PowerShell script from my Batch to zip the backup, but I get this error:

[image]

This happens becaus the .bat file is running. I've checked.

The code for both the batch and power shell script follows:

**BATCH:**

```
echo "========================================="
echo "=====| Backuping DCT Light's Files |====="
echo "========================================="

SET dct-light_src=\\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\DCT_NEW

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dct_light_startting_date=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set dct_light_startting_time=%%a%%b)

SET starttime=%dct_light_startting_date%

CD C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /A "N=0"
FOR /F %%f IN ('DIR /B /A:-D "*"') DO (SET /A "N=!N!+1")

IF %n% == 5 (

powershell.exe -noexit -file "C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\remove_oldest.ps1"

) ELSE (
    IF EXIST C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%starttime%\ ( 
        MD C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%starttime%\dctlight_backup
        SET dct-light_dtn=C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%starttime%\dctlight_backup
        echo A folder for this backup already exists. Beggining overwrite...
    ) ELSE ( 
        MD C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%starttime%\dctlight_backup
        SET dct-light_dtn=C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%starttime%\dctlight_backup\
    )   
)
CD C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\backup_completo
XCOPY %dct-light_src% %dct-light_dtn% /w /e /y /EXCLUDE:C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\backup_completo\exclusion.txt

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dct_light_finished_date=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set dct_light_finished_time=%%a%%b)

SET startdate=%dct_light_finished_date%
SET starttime=%dct_light_startting_date%_%dct_light_startting_time%
SET finishedtime=%dct_light_finished_date%_%dct_light_finished_time%

CD C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%startdate%\

echo.LOG of %starttime%'s Backup>LOG_%startdate%.txt
echo.Start time: %starttime%>>LOG_%startdate%.txt
echo.Finished time: %finishedtime%>>LOG_%startdate%.txt

CD C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%startdate%\dctlight_backup\

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /A "N=0"
FOR /F %%f IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D "*"') DO (SET /A "N=!N!+1")

CD ../
echo.Files copied: %N%>>LOG_%startdate%.txt

powershell.exe -noexit -file "C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\zip_backups.ps1"

pause>nul
```

**POWER SHELL:**

```
#DCT Light's zipping
Start-Sleep -s 15
$source = "C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light"
$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
$destination = "C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_$date.zip"

If(Test-path $destination) {Remove-item $destination}
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)

Remove-Item $source\* -Recurse -Exclude *.zip
```

What I have tried to solve the problem:

1. Create a `Master.ps1` with a list of scripts to run, where the first one is, obliviously, the backup batch file and then the zipping ps1 file.
2. Call the zipping ps1 file from the backup batch file on another window and then kill the batch. In this case, the first line of the zipping script was:

   `Start-Sleep -s 15`

So I was certain that the batch was killed before I really started zipping.

None of the above worked. Any help? If nothing works I'll just schedule them as separated tasks on Windows.

Comment: Seems like you have answered your own question. Just look at your code.  It is pretty obvious the batch file still has the folder in use. The batch file is sitting here: `C:\Users\william_silva4\Desktop\tools_backup\dct_light\dctlight_backup_%startdate%` and that is the folder the Powershell script is trying to use.  So do another change directory to get out of the folder path with your batch file.

Comment: @Squashman how so? Even if I CD to the C: drive before trying to open the zipping script, it still fails. Can you be more specific? Maybe some sample code?

Comment: Actually the problem is your Powershell script.  You are writing out the ZIP file to the same location you are backing up.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Squashman. It seems like you're right. It worked.

Comment: @Squashman, now, do you have any idea on how can I delete the source folder of my zip? That folder cannot be deleted because it is being used by another process (in this case the very same Power Shell that zipped it). Also, I'd love to accept your answer if you'd like to post it.